# Is 10.16.17.0/24 a class A IP address with with Class C subnetting?

Tags: ip, subnet

We know that 
 
Class A: IP addresses are those between 0.0.0.0 and 127.255.255.255.
Class B: IP addresses are those between 128.0.0.0 and 191.255.255.255.
Class C: IP addresses are those between 192.0.0.0 and 223.255.255.255. 
And that for Class A, the first 8 bits are network bits.
Now when I see 10.16.17.0/24 Isn't the first 24 bits the fixed as network bits?

Comment: We also know that classful networking was **obsoleted in 1993**, nearly thirty years ago. Please leave it dead and buried.

Comment: Interesting....

Answer (score 0):

You should use past tense - *were* those between. Classful networking was made obsolete by CIDR ([RFC 1518](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1518) & [1519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1519)) decades ago in 1993.

> when I see 10.16.17.0/24 Isn't the first 24 bits the fixed as network bits?

The `/24` indicates CIDR notation, so historic network classes aren't relevant.

Classful networking defined an allocation and *default* network mask for the Class A range (`0.0.0.0/1`) of 8 bits (or `/8` in CIDR). VLSM allowed subnetting that default prefix as required, in this case down to `/24` - 8 default prefix bits, 16 subnet bits, 8 host bits. Back in the day you'd have used `10.16.17.0/255.255.255.0`, however.